# Series of nested loops without recursion

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, nested-loops

In Java, I have the following general code for integer `d` equal to `2, 3, 4, ..., dmax` - up to a maximum number `dmax : d < dmax` (so this code is repeated for every value of `d` in that range):

```
// d is the number of wrapper loops
int[] ls = new int[d];
...
// let ls array be filled with some arbitrary positive numbers here
...
// first wrapper loop
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ls[0]; i1++) {

    ...

        // last wrapper loop
        for (int id = 0; id < ls[d - 1]; id++) {

            // internal loop
            for (int j = id + 1; j < ls[d - 1]; j++) {

                myCode();

            }

        }

    ...

}
```

In case of `d = 3` it looks like:

```
int ls = new int[3];
ls[0] = 5; ls[1] = 7; ls[2] = 5;

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ls[0]; i1++) {

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < ls[1]; i2++) {

        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < ls[2]; i3++) {

            for (int j = i3 + 1; j < ls[2]; j++) {

                myCode();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I want to gather all that repeated code into a single generalized one. For that purpose I can use the `while` loop and recursion like below:

```
int d = 2, dmax = 10;
while (d < dmax) {
    // in algorithm ls is pre-filled, here its length is shown for clearance
    int[] ls = new int[d];
    for (int i = 0; i < ls[0]; i++) {
        doRecursiveLoop(1, d, -1, ls);
    }
    d++;
}

doRecursiveLoop(int c, int d, int index, int[] ls) {

    if (c < d) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ls[c]; i++) {
            // only on the last call we give the correct index, otherwise -1
            if (c == d - 1) index = i;
            doRecursiveLoop(c + 1, d, index, ls);
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = index + 1; j < ls[d - 1]; j++) {

            myCode();

        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody shed some light as to how I would approach this problem of dynamically occurred nested loops without recursion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ : dynamic number of nested for loops (without recursion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732974/c-dynamic-number-of-nested-for-loops-without-recursion)

Comment: Answer #1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30290814/864113
Answer #2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18733552/864113

Answer (score 1):

You effectively have [*tail recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) here.  Any tail-recursive function can [trivially be converted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion#Relation_to_while_construct) to an iterative function using a loop.

For example:

```
void foo() {
    // ... Stuff ...

    if (someCondition) {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
void foo() {
    while (someCondition) {
        // ... Stuff ...
    }
    bar();
}
```

Comment: In my question there is a solution with recursion, but I want to do that iteratively!

Comment: @SophieSperner: Yes; and you can convert it using the techniques in the links above...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while it has the *form* of tail recursion, Java itself doesn't support tail recursion, so it's not actually tail recursive.

Comment: @RyanStewart: I think what you mean is that Java  compilers don't support *tail call elimination*.  That doesn't make this not tail-recursive.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer. No need to vote for it :)

Comment: @SophieSperner: It's exactly an answer.  The only thing I haven't done is write the code for you ;)