# how can we do n nested for loops where n is dynamic

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I have read the following questions but have not found a solution to my problem:

- [c++ : dynamic number of nested for loops (without recursion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732974/c-dynamic-number-of-nested-for-loops-without-recursion)
- [variable nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555864/variable-nested-for-loops)

actual problem statement is :-

> Job and Jimmy both are playing with numbers. Job gives Jimmy an array of numbers and asks him to tell the minimum possible last number of a non decreasing sequence of length L.
>
> Input Format
>
> First input line consists of a number which is size of array N.
>
> Next line contains N space separated elements of array.
>
> Next line contains length of the non decreasing sequence i.e. L.
>
> Output Format
>
> You have to print the minimum possible last number of a sequence and if their is no non-decreasing sequence of length L, then print -1
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 7
> 9 7 2 5 4 11 12
> 3
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 11
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> In sample input, possible non-decreasing sequences of length L=3 are (9,11,12) , (7,11,12) , (2,5,11) , (2,4,11) , (2,5,12) , (2,4,12) , (2,11,12) , (5,11,12) , (4,11,12) and the minimum last number is 11 for the sequences (2,5,11) and (2,4,11). Hence, the answer is 11."

my code...

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int fact(int y,int x)
    {
    static int temp=0;
    if(temp==x)
    {
        temp=0;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        {
        ++temp;
        return y*fact((y-1),x);
    }
}

int main() {
    int num,randmax,n,s,q,w last=-1, minlast=-1;
    
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    
    for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
        {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cin>>s;
    vector<vector<int>> c;
    q=fact(s);
    c.resize(q);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < q ; ++i)
    {
        //Grow Columns by n
        a[i].resize(s);
    }
    w=q;
    randmax=n-1;
    int k=0;
    while(w)
        {
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            
        }
        num=rand()%randmax; // this works perfect as expected
        c[][i]=a[num];
        }
        w--;
    }
    /*for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
            for(int k=j+1;k<n; k++)
                {
                    if((a[i]<=a[j])&&(a[j]<=a[k]))
                        {
                        last=a[k];
                        
                        if(minlast=-1)
                        {
                            minlast=a[k];
                        }
                        if(last<minlast){
                            minlast=last;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    */
    cout<<last;
    return 0;
}
```

`

I would tell you what I tried to do... I thought of mapping the data by having them randomly assigned in one of my array and then computing them..

I got lost somewhere in my code...plz gimme an solution to it...and more imp. a good explanation of the same as I got stuck at times when I need a dynamic nested n loop type of thing...

also it would be more helpful if you edit in my code or algo so that I could learn where my mistakes are there...

Thanks in advance for you time...

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks for edi

Comment: You already found quite a few answers to your question, but you're asking for more. What do you not get about the other answers? Ask us something specific that the existing answers don't cover, or this is just another duplicate and will be closed as such.

Comment: @user2357112 can we do that without recursion...like i find recursion wuite overwhelming ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answers your links have pointed out, you can imitate a dynamic amount of for loops by using an array [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30808351) gives a fine implementation here.

For the actual problem you gave though, I see no need for a dynamic amount of for loops at all. The problem is a standard non-decreasing subsequence problem with a slight variation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int N, L;
int arr[100], seq[100];
int bst;

int main() {
    std::ifstream file ("c.txt");

    file >> N;
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        file >> arr[n];
    file >> L;
    file.close();

    bst = 1e9;
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) seq[i] = 1e9;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int x = 0;
        while(seq[x] < arr[i]) ++x;
        seq[x] = arr[i];
        if(x + 1 >= L) 
            bst = std::min(bst, arr[i]);
    }

    std::cout << bst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code should solve your problem. The first part does standard parsing and initialization. The rest is a variation on the [LIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem, which has several standard algorithms that solve it. Here, we just check that whenever we extend an array of length L or longer, we see if the element is smaller than our current.