# Solve all 2d string vector combinations without using recursion? (C++ )

Tags: c++, arrays, string, recursion, vector

The problem is:

Create a function that computes all combinations of an array of arrays of strings, e.g.: `{ { "red", "wooden", "gate" }, { "lazy", "little", "man" }, { "what", "where", "who", "why" } }` to output: red lazy what, red lazy where, red lazy who, red lazy why, red little what, etc.....

This function will print all combinations of one word from the first array, one word from the second array, one word from the third array, etc.

***Your solution may not use recursion***

NOTE: the number of arrays and number of elements within each array may vary! Your method needs to be able to handle this.

---

I'm trying to practice my algorithms and this problem is just driving me crazy. I've tried brainstorming a few things but at this point, have spent hours getting nowhere. I was reworking my thoughts into another nested loop (see below...) when it occurred to me that maybe I just need to create a vector of strings (this would become a very large vector though...for now, lets call this vector `endings`). If I traverse backward in the outer vector of the given `vector<vector<string>>` and update `endings` by attaching each ending to each string in the current outer vector, then by the time I get to the first outer vector, all of my combinations will be in `endings`.

I probably didn't think of this immediately because I assumed if I was only printing, I shouldn't be storing so much. Anyway, here is some botched code that I stopped working on to post this. It's not much.

```
vector<vector<string>> ar = {{"red", "wooden", "gate"}, 
                             {"lazy", "little", "man"}, 
                             {"what", "where", "who", "why"}};

vector<string> res(ar.size());

for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {   
    res[i]= ar[i][0];
}

int i;

for (i = ar.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = arr.size()-1-i, j > arr.size()-1-i; j--) {
                // ...
    }
}
```

Let me know how you suggest solving this problem.

Comment: Hint: you could use a stack to convert any recursion to iteration

Comment: look at the source code of std::next_permuatation

Comment: @RichardHodges this has nothing to do with permutations.

Comment: Say all your string arrays have the same content, `{"0","1"}`.  Assume there are four of them. What kind of output do you expect? What if they all contain `{"0","1","2"}`? (Now the critical part) what if some contain `{"0","1"}` and others contain `{"0","1","2"}`, can you cope with that?

Comment: Hi, maybe this SO article may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732974/c-dynamic-number-of-nested-for-loops-without-recursion

Answer (score 5):

"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" - David Wheeler

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const& astrs, std::vector<std::size_t> const& idxs)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < astrs.size() ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << sep << astrs[i][idxs[i]];
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

bool next_in_sequence(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const& astrs, std::vector<std::size_t>& idxs)
{
    for(std::size_t i = astrs.size() ; i-- ; )
    {
        if(++idxs[i] != astrs[i].size())
        {
            return true;
        }
        idxs[i] = 0;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const ar = {
        {"red", "wooden", "gate"}, 
        {"lazy", "little", "man"}, 
        {"what", "where", "who", "why"}
    };

    vector<std::size_t> idxs(ar.size(), 0);

    do
    {
        print(ar, idxs);
    }
    while(next_in_sequence(ar, idxs));
}
```

This solution builds an array of indecies. Think of this array as an integer where each digit column has its own base. The base is the number of strings in the corresponding 'slot' in `ar` + 1.

All we need to do is "increment" the "integer" until it wraps. This is performed in the function `next_in_sequence()`.

Here is another way of expressing this idea. It's conceptually less efficient (in reality, maybe not for 'small' input sets), but demonstrates the idea the other way around - compute the maximum number of combinations, iterate through each one and compute the 'digits' of our multi-base index representation as we go. It requires no additional storage, at the expense of repeating computations:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::size_t combinations_at(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const& astrs, std::size_t col)
{
    std::size_t result = 1;
    while (col != astrs.size())
    {
        result *= astrs[col].size();
        ++col;
    }
    return result;
}

void print(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const& astrs, std::size_t which)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    for(std::size_t col = 0 ; col != astrs.size() ; ++col)
    {
        auto nextmod = combinations_at(astrs, col + 1);
        auto i = which / nextmod;
        which %= nextmod;
        std::cout << sep << astrs[col][i];
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> const ar = {
        {"red", "wooden", "gate"},
        {"lazy", "little", "man"},
        {"what", "where", "who", "why"}
    };

    const auto limit = combinations_at(ar, 0);
    for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < limit ; ++i)
        print(ar, i);
}
```

Comment: Could you please rename you function to `combination` as this really is not a permutation (or maybe I missed something). Also showing the output would be nice.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName I don't think it's a combination either. Have renamed to `next_in_sequence`

Comment: @RichardHodges So I've had a very busy week and am finally getting the chance to go through this on paper/really analyze what happens during each iteration.... (Funny how stuff like this is so dire at 3 am, then put on the back-burner the next day). ANYWAY- this is very very cool, I'm impressed at how "simple" the solution really is. Thank you for sharing and explaining. Great way of thinking.

Comment: @Bella happy to have helped.