# using decltype w/ parameter pack for C++11

Tags: c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, auto

I'm trying to get the `multi_index_t` code from the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290535/creating-n-nested-for-loops/30290814#30290814) answered by davidhigh to work with C++11. C++11 does not support `auto&` type returns.

I converted the return types for the class, but I don't understand how/if it's possible to support the helper function `multi_index()` without using C++14.

The code:

```
#include<array>

template<int dim>
struct multi_index_t
{
  std::array<int, dim> size_array;
  template<typename ... Args>
  multi_index_t(Args&& ... args) : size_array(std::forward<Args>(args) ...) {}

  struct iterator
  {
    struct sentinel_t {};
    std::array<int, dim> index_array = {};
    std::array<int, dim> const& size_array;
    bool _end = false;

    iterator(std::array<int, dim> const& size_array) : size_array(size_array) {}

    iterator& operator++() 
    {
      for (int i = 0;i < dim;++i)
      {
        if (index_array[i] < size_array[i] - 1)
        {
          ++index_array[i];
          for (int j = 0;j < i;++j) { index_array[j] = 0; }
          return *this;
        }
      }
      _end = true;
      return *this;
    }
    std::array<int, dim>& operator*()  { return index_array; }
    bool operator!=(sentinel_t) const { return !_end; }
  };

  iterator begin() const { return iterator{ size_array }; }
  iterator end() const { return typename iterator::sentinel_t{}; }
};


template<typename ... index_t>
auto multi_index(index_t&& ... index) // <-- this doesn't compile
{
  static constexpr int size = sizeof ... (index_t); 
  auto ar = std::array<int, size>{std::forward<index_t>(index) ...};
  return multi_index_t<size>(ar);
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function), you can't recursively expand the variadic function template via `decltype()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C++11 does not support `auto&` type returns.

So you can simply explicit the types.

For `multi_index()` you have that return a `multi_index_t<size>`, where `size` is `sizeof...(index_t)`, so you can write

```
template<typename ... index_t>
multi_index_t<sizeof...(index_t)> multi_index(index_t&& ... index)
```

> According to this answer, you can't recursively expand the variadic function template via `decltype`.

Correct, but I don't see recursion in your `multi_index()` function, so I don't see how apply recursion over `decltype()`.

If you really want (but why?), you can explicit the returning type through `decltype()` as follows

```
template<typename ... index_t>
auto multi_index(index_t&& ... index)
   -> decltype( multi_index_t<sizeof...(index_t)>
                   { std::array<int, sizeof...(index_t)>
                        {{ std::forward<index_t>(index) ... }} } )
```

but I don't see a reason to do this instead of simply explicit `multi_index_t<sizeof...(index_t)>`

Comment: This answered my question. I was fixated on using decltype. Thanks max