# Linearize nested for loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, math

I'm working on some heavy algorithm, and now I'm trying to make it multithreaded. It has a loop with 2 nested loops:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < n; ++k) {
            function(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

I know, that the number of `function` calls will be equal to

[image]

But I have one last problem: I don't know how to calculate `i`, `j` and `k` based on `b` (`0 <= b < binom(n, 3)`)

```cpp
for (int b = start; b < end; ++b) {
    // how to calculate i, j, k?
}
```

How can I calculate these values?

**EDIT**:
My main idea is to call function like this from different threads:

```cpp
void calculate(int start, int end) {
    for (int b = start; b < end; ++b) {
        int i = ...;
        int j = ...;
        int k = ...;
        function(i, j, k);
    }
}

int total = binom(n, 3);

// thread A:
calculate(0, total / 2);

// thread B:
calculate(total / 2, total);
```

Comment: What exactly is b? I don't think I understand the question...

Comment: So to be clear: You are asking how to split up the work between the different threads?

Comment: @MichalBurgunder yes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number

Comment: Why not leaving the 3 for loops within `calculate` and have each thread call `calculate` for `[0, total/2)` and `[total/2, total)` as you currently do? At the end, the number of calls (complexity) is the same, and you calculate `i`, `j` and `k` with an increment instead of with a formula (faster).

Comment: @rturrado yeah, it will be definitely faster, but it doesn't solve the main problem - I'm still don't know how to calculate `i`, `j` and `k`

Comment: @congard Cool; I took for granted that you were looking for performance when changing your code to a multithreaded one, but I understand that shouldn't be necessarily the case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a math question that doesn't seems to have direct relation with programming. You may want to ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another take on your problem. As said in the comments, what you are looking for is basically finding the successor and the unranking of combinations. For this I use the algorithms from the book 'Combinatorial algorithms' of Kreher and Stinson.

Here is the corresponding code consisting of the two functions `next` and `unrank` as well as a helper for the binomial coefficient which is required in the unranking function:

```
int binomial ( int n, int k )
{
    int mn = k;
    if ( n - k < mn )
    {
        mn = n - k;
    }

    if ( mn < 0 ) { return 0; }
    if ( mn == 0 ) { return 1; }

    int mx = k;
    if ( mx < n - k )
    {
        mx = n - k;
    }
    int value = mx + 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= mn; ++i)
    {
        value = ( value * ( mx + i ) ) / i;
    }

    return value;
}         
        
auto unrank(int rank, int n, int k)
{    
    std::vector<int> t(k);
    
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int b = binomial ( n - x, k - i - 1);
            if (b > rank) break;
            rank -= b;
            ++x;
        }
    
        t[i] = x;
        ++x;
    }

  return t;
}

auto next(std::vector<int>& index, int n, int k)
{
    for (int i = k-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (index[i] < n - (k-1) + i)
        {
            ++index[i];
            for (int j = i+1; j < k; ++j)
            {
                index[j] = index[j-1]+1;
            }                    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The idea is then to generate the initial index-configuration from a given start address, and then compute the successor of this index `(end-start)` times. Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 7;
    int k = 4;
    
    int start = 3;
    int end = 10;

    auto index = unrank(start,n,k);        
    auto print_index = [&]()
    {
        for(auto const& ind : index)
        {
            std::cout<<ind<<"  ";  
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    };

    print_index();
    for(int i=start; i<end; ++i)
    {
        next(index, n, k);
        print_index();            
    }
}
```

which prints

```
1  2  3  7  
1  2  4  5  
1  2  4  6  
1  2  4  7  
1  2  5  6  
1  2  5  7  
1  2  6  7  
1  3  4  5
```

And here is the [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acde4c99ee728075). Enjoy!

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you. It is much faster than atomics, moreover, it seems like there is a ≈constant overhead compared to plain loops

Comment: @congard: by the way: if you want to speed up this code, i.e., reduce the constant overhead, apply a *memoizing* binomial function.

Comment: Hi, I've found an issue in your `unrank` implementation, here is a [demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a372a4402fe89002)

Comment: @congard: blame it on Kreher/Stinson, or on my implementation of it. Sorry, I don't have the time to provide second level support -- you have the basics now, I'd suggest you to go on and fix it yourself.

Comment: @congard: actually it's December 23rd and not that much at work :-) so I had a look at your code: the error is that you input wrong parameters: auto index = unrank(start,n+1,k);. The n+1 is wrong. It should be just n, otherwise its insconsistent. In order to get what you want, I changed the upper index in the `next` function. Here is the corrected [code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d6497cdeb1f84a4).

Comment: Well, but try start=4 (`1  3  5 | 1  4  5`) and then start=5 (`1  3  6 | 1  4  5 `). Unfortunately, the same issue :(

Comment: @congard: You're right, and you know why? Because I've built in yet another bug in my trial for optimization :-) I wanted to avoid the two-time calculation of the same binomial coefficient. I fixed it now in a different way, and here is the correct [code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9471352cf55830db).

Answer (score 3):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290814/2412846), I shared a class named `multi_index` which basically does what you want, i.e.

```
for(auto m : multi_index(3,3,4))
{
    // now m[i] holds index of i-th loop
    // m[0] goes from 0 to 2
    // m[1] goes from 0 to 2
    // m[2] goes from 0 to 3
    std::cout<<m[0]<<" "<<m[1]<<" "<<m[2]<<std::endl;
}
```

However, this code is for "normal" loops only, where each dimension runs from `0` to some upper value.

In this post, I'll try to apply this to the antisymmetric case where `m[i]<m[j]` for `i<j`. The basic idea of the linked code remains the same, namely to create a class that holds the loop boundaries and provides an iterator which can be used with a range-based for loop. The only difference is that I use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array` as the index array type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

struct antisym_index_t
{
    int upper_index;
    int dim;
    antisym_index_t(int upper_index, int dim) : upper_index(upper_index), dim(dim) {}

    struct iterator
    {
        struct sentinel_t {};

        int upper_index;
        int dim;
        std::vector<int> index_array = {};
        bool _end = false;

        iterator(int upper_index, int dim) : upper_index(upper_index), dim(dim), index_array(dim)
        {
            std::iota(std::begin(index_array), std::end(index_array),0);
        }

        auto& operator++()
        {
            for (int i = dim-1;i >= 0;--i)
            {
                if (index_array[i] < upper_index - 1 - (dim-1-i))
                {
                    ++index_array[i];
                    for (int j = i+1;j < dim;++j)
                    {
                        index_array[j] = index_array[j-1]+1;
                    }                    
                    return *this;
                }
            }
            _end = true;
            return *this;
        }
        auto& operator*()
        {
            return index_array;
        }
        bool operator!=(sentinel_t) const
        {
            return !_end;
        }
    };

    auto begin() const
    {
        return iterator{ upper_index, dim };
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return typename iterator::sentinel_t{};
    }
};

auto antisym_index(int upper_index, int dim)
{
    return antisym_index_t(upper_index, dim);
}
```

Note, however, that this code is untested so far (written on top of my head). You can use it as

```
for(auto m : antisym_index(5,3))
{
    // now m[i] holds index of i-th loop
    std::cout<<m[0]<<" "<<m[1]<<" "<<m[2]<<std::endl;
}
```

EDIT: by, now, I've tested and corrected the code, see [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c899efeb1d4d5f2). Memo to myself: don't publish untested code.

EDIT2: by the way, this answers your question inside the question. It's not clear to me, how this should help with multitasking.

Comment: quite interesting solution, but unfortunately it works with "normal" loops only, it has only `upper_index` but I also need something like `lower_index` (i.e start index not equal to 0). But you gave me an idea which I will try to implement later. Not sure that it will solve my problem completely, but I hope that at least it will be a temporary solution

Comment: @congard: After reading your question again, it seems to me that what you want is called "unranking" of combinations. That is, you enter a number which is the address of a given index (aka combination), and you get back the components of the index. It's pretty standard in numerical combinatorics, but if you don't get, tell me so I could post some code.

Comment: if you could, please post some code. I will be grateful

Comment: @congard: no problem, but you have to wait until tomorrow... I have to take the code from my other PC. Give me a hint, if I forget it.

Comment: * just reminding you *

Comment: @congard: See the other answer I posted, which I did because I have the feeling, you don't need all this fancy 'range-based for-loop' stuff. I'll let it stand however because you can also enhance this other answer in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full answer, but a solution for 2 loops. My sleep-deprived mind cannot generalize this to 3 loops but maybe someone else can.

In 2D the problem becomes figuring out the row and column index of a triangular matrix from a flattened index. This makes it easy to see that the end that "tapers off" is contained in the larger one. In ASCII art something like this:

```
      n
 ___________
|_          |
| |_        |
|   |_      |
|   | |_    |
|   |   |_  |
|___|_____|_|
  i   ^
      |
     binom(n-i, 2)
```

So, let's define

- `n` loop end index (number of matrix rows/columns)
- `i` outer loop counter range [0, n). As drawn: column index
- `j` inner loop counter range [0, i). As drawn: row index from bottom up
- `a` flattened loop counter range [0, binom(n, 2))

Then `i` can be computed from `binom(n, 2) - binom(n-i, 2) = a`. One round-trip through Wolfram Alpha gives us:

- `i = trunc(-0.5 * sqrt((1 - 2 n)**2 - 8 a) + n - 0.5)`.

The truncation (=cast to int) "rounds down" to the last full column. So the row index `j` can be computed from as

- `j = a - (binom(n, 2) - binom(n-i, 2))`
- `j = a - i*(-i + 2 n - 1) / 2`

Answer (score 1):

A third attempt:

I've taken your code, and at last got it to run properly (in python):

```
def get_k(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(3, n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                total += 1
            
    V = total // 2 # for 2 threads
    V_tmp = 0          
    for i in range(3, n):
        if(V_tmp > V):
            return i
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                V_tmp += 1

def pseudo_thread(start, end, n):
    counter = 0

    for i in range(start, end):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                counter += 1
    print(counter)


n = 145
k = get_k(n)

pseudo_thread(3, k, n)
pseudo_thread(k, n, n)
```

This should finally give you a relatively good split. Even with n=145, we get 239260 and 227920 for our counter values. It's obviously not an elegant solution, and also not perfect, but it gives you the right answer without much reference to detailed mathematics.

Comment: "Splitting the computation as above will cause your threads to compute different amounts of values" but why? Since (for example) thread A executes `calculate(0, total / 2)` and thread B `calculate(total / 2, total)` (where total = binom(n, 3)) So `end1 - start1 == end2 - start2`

Comment: It seems that V should be `(n)*(n-1)*(n-2) / 6` (because binom(n, 3) = n!/((n-3)! * 3!). I've tested your example, and unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. I've written [a simple python script](https://www.online-python.com/26fA0vQWLb) for testing, and you can see, that unfortunately, it prints different values (116 and 4). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to parallelize, you could also use an atomic struct and implement the iteration with compare-and-swap operations. There is a 16 byte CAS on most platforms. Link with `-latomic` on GCC. Clang inlines the CAS calls if we ensure proper alignment.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

/**
 * Index for a nested loop
 *
 * Index for loop in style
 * for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
 *   for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
 *     for(k = 0; k < j; ++k);
 *
 * The total number of iterations is binom(n, 3)
 *
 * Indices are int for two reasons:
 * 1. Keep overall size at or below 16 byte to allow atomic operations
 * 2. The total number of iterations reaches 2^64 at n ~ 4.8 million
 */
struct Index {
  int i, j, k;

  constexpr Index() noexcept
  : i(2), j(1), k(0)
  {}
  Index& operator++() noexcept
  {
    if(k + 1 < j) {
      ++k;
      return *this;
    }
    k = 0;
    if(j + 1 < i) {
      ++j;
      return *this;
    }
    j = 0;
    ++i;
    return *this;
  }
};

/**
 * Padds Index to power of 2 alignment up to 16 byte
 *
 * This improves atomic operation performance because it avoids
 * split-locks. Not sure if GCC's std::atomic makes actual use of this
 * but clang does.
 */
struct AlignedIndex
{
private:
  static constexpr std::size_t alignment =
    sizeof(Index) < 2 ? 1 :
    sizeof(Index) < 3 ? 2 :
    sizeof(Index) < 5 ? 4 :
    sizeof(Index) < 9 ? 8 :
    16;
public:
  union {
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Index), alignment>::type pod;
    Index index;
  };
  constexpr AlignedIndex() noexcept
  : index()
  {}
};

Index increment(std::atomic<AlignedIndex>& index) noexcept
{
  AlignedIndex last = index.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  AlignedIndex next;
  do {
    next = last;
    ++next.index;
  } while(! index.compare_exchange_weak(last, next, std::memory_order_relaxed));
  return last.index;
}

int main()
{
  std::atomic<AlignedIndex> index(AlignedIndex{});
  int n = 5;
  for(Index cur; (cur = increment(index)).i < n; ) {
    std::printf("%d %d %d\n", cur.i, cur.j, cur.k);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but not as I expected: I need a combinations generator, but at 2nd iteration, your solution gives `3 0 0`. However, after some modifications, it will work as expected. I had a similar idea with mutexes, but it looks like your code will be faster. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating from 1..binom(n, 3), just iterate from 1..n^3 (conceptually the cartesian product of the set of numbers 1..n with itself 2x, as opposed to the combinations of 3 elements without repetition). In doing so, we can easily calculate i/j/k from M:

```
k = (M / N^0) % N = M % N
j = (M / N^1) % N
i = (M / N^2) % N = M / N^2
```

Sure, this will result in duplicates, but we're not going to skip the duplicates one by one. Once we reach a number where `k>=j`, we need to increment `b` by `(N-k)*N^0 = N-k` to cause it to "wrap around" to `0` again. Same goes for `j>=i` - increment `b` by `(N-j)*N^1`, to wrap around.

In doing so, we arrive back at just the original set of numbers. There's some overhead of division and modulus calculations, which can repeat up to once per variable (minus the first variable), so yes, there's some overhead, but its constant, for a constant number of variables.

Comment: it will work, but the main goal is to split the work between threads so each thread should do the same amount of work. If just split n^3 into 4 equal ranges, then in the first one there will be much more work to do than in the last one

Comment: @congard don't split them into 3 big "chunks", split them into 3 slices (i.e. use `%` not `/`). That way thread 1 gets `1, 4, 7, 10...`, thread 2 ``2, 5, 8, ...` so on. In that way, it will balance out

Comment: could you provide an example, please?

Comment: @congard For 0<=k<j<i<N, M=i*N^2+j*N+k, and N=10, we'd iterate over M from [0, 10^3). We divide these values of M_b amongst the the 3 threads. Instead of being {01,2,..,N^3/3}, {1+N^3/3, 2+N^3/3, ..., 2*N^3/3}, {1+2*N^3/3, 2+2*N^3/3, ..., N^3} (continuous chunks), we kinda "interleave" the elements of each set-  {0,3,6,..., N^3-2}, {1,4,7, ..., N^3-1}, {2,5,8,..., N^3}.  (There may be a few off by one errors in there, but you get the idea)

Comment: In reality, this pattern is suboptimal anyways- I realized that sometime after posting my answer 2 days ago. It adds a lot of overhead doing this math- the best strategy is probably to solve for `i_a*(i_a-1)*(i_a-2) = N*(N-1)*(N-2)*X_a` for `i_0` and `i_1` when `X_1=1/3` and `X_2=2/3` to find the two values of `i` to split the outermost loop. Then, in each thread, iterate over all valid values of `j` and `k` in the appropriate intervals (`{0<=i<i_1}, {i_1<=i<i<i_2}, {i_2<=i<N}`). Minimal overhead, and relatively balanced between threads (asymptotically speaking).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on [Dillon Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6221024/dillon-davis) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70425787/9200394).

```cpp
auto divide = [](float pos, int len) -> float {
    auto n = static_cast<float>(len);

    if (pos == 1) {
        return n;
    }

    if (pos == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // solve   x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) = n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * pos   for x
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

    float d = n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (1 - pos);

    auto f = [d](float x) {
        return std::pow(x, 3) - 3 * std::pow(x, 2) + 2 * x - d;
    };

    float a = 0;
    float b = n;
    float epsilon = 0.1f;

    float x = 0;

    while (std::abs(a - b) > epsilon) {
        x = (a + b) / 2;

        if (std::abs(f(x)) <= epsilon) {
            break;
        } else if (f(x) * f(a) < 0) {
            b = x;
        } else {
            a = x;
        }
    }

    return std::ceil(n - x);
};
```

It's pretty fast and with minimal overhead, but it's not as accurate as [davidhigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429200/9200394)'s solution, which allows splitting 'work' into equal parts.

Example:

```cpp
auto testRun = [](int begin, int end, int n) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; ++k) {
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter << "\n";
};

int n = 1200;
int ranges = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < ranges; ++i) {
    auto begin = static_cast<int>(divide((float) i / (float) ranges, n));
    auto end = static_cast<int>(divide((float) (i + 1) / (float) ranges, n));
    testRun(begin, end, n);
}
```

Output:

```
72035920
71897080
71619380
71728020
```